# When I try to serve an Ionic v1 project to browser, I got such npm error hints which I can't understand:

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, npm, gulp

When I try to serve an Ionic v1 project to browser, I got such `npm` error hints which I can't understand:

```
"D:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2017.1.2\bin\runnerw.exe" "D:\Program Files\nodejs\ionic.cmd" serve

[INFO] --confirm: Detected .\gulpfile.js in project directory,
       but to integrate gulp with the CLI, you'll need to install @ionic/cli-plugin-gulp.
       Install now? Yes

> npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-gulp@latest
```

[after a long while...]

```
× Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running npm install --save-dev --save-exact
        @ionic/cli-plugin-gulp@latest (exit code 1):

        npm WARN my-project-name@1.1.1 No repository field.
        npm WARN my-project-name@1.1.1 No license field.

        npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined

        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!
        C:\Users\my-user-name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-27T16_12_36_428Z-debug.log
```

So I can't build my `Ionic v1` project now. I'm not familiar with `npm` and `node.js`. What does these hints mean?

The log that it mentioned is a huge file with 3709 lines, which is even more harder to understand for me than the error hints. I post the last part of it as following:

```
2610 silly unbuild uuid
2611 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2612 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2613 silly unbuild string-width
2614 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2615 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2616 silly unbuild signal-exit
2617 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2618 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2619 silly unbuild safe-buffer
2620 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2621 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2622 silly unbuild qs
2623 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2624 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2625 silly unbuild pseudomap
2626 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2627 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2628 silly unbuild path-is-absolute
2629 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2630 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2631 silly unbuild os-tmpdir
2632 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2633 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2634 silly unbuild form-data
2635 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2636 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2637 silly unbuild mime-types
2638 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2639 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2640 silly unbuild mime-db
2641 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2642 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2643 silly unbuild lodash.assign
2644 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2645 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2646 silly unbuild is-fullwidth-code-point
2647 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2648 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2649 silly unbuild fs.realpath
2650 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2651 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2652 silly unbuild combined-stream
2653 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2654 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2655 silly unbuild delayed-stream
2656 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2657 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2658 silly unbuild block-stream
2659 info lifecycle undefined~preuninstall: undefined
2660 info lifecycle undefined~uninstall: undefined
2661 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\my-user-name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-54df09edb4a547d6.lock for E:\Projects\myApp\node_modules\.staging
2662 warn my-project-name@1.1.1 No repository field.
2663 warn my-project-name@1.1.1 No license field.
2664 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
2664 verbose stack     at rmStuff (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\unbuild.js:61:24)
2664 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
2664 verbose stack     at ret (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promisify.js:184:12), <anonymous>:13:39)
2664 verbose stack     at lifecycle.then.then (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\unbuild.js:12:12)
2664 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
2664 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
2664 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
2664 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
2664 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
2664 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
2664 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
2664 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
2664 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:651:20)
2664 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:624:5)
2664 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:596:5)
2665 verbose cwd E:\Projects\YLCloudWater
2666 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
2667 verbose argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev" "--save-exact" "@ionic/cli-plugin-gulp@latest"
2668 verbose node v7.6.0
2669 verbose npm  v5.3.0
2670 error Cannot read property '0' of undefined
2671 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I guess you have to check `2017-08-27T16_12_36_428Z-debug.log` file. The error message is not clear.

Comment: @yogurt It's a huge file with 3709 lines, which is even more harder to understand for me than the error hints. I've edited the question and posted the last part of it.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for this but you may try using nodejs version 6 (lts) or 8 (latest). It might be a problem about nodejs and your version is not supported I guess.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll have a try as you suggested.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm waiting for your response :-)

Comment: @yogurt I'm working in the environment of WebStorm. I opened File->Settings->Languages & Frameworks->Node.js and NPM, in which all the packages currently installed are listed. And I just found only one package is not up-to-date currently, which is `ionic`. So I click `Upgrade` button to upgrade it from 3.5.0 to the latest (3.9.2). I noticed the version of `node.exe` is 7.6.0. And `Node.js Core library is disabled`, So I click `enable` button to enable it. After I've done these, I served the project again, and this time, everything is OK. The error hints did not come up again.

Comment: Then, have fun with development in Ionic!

Comment: @yogurt But I think there's still something wrong. Because I can run `npm install jshint --save-dev` and `npm install async --save-dev` in the Node.js directory. But I can't run these two commands in my project directory. So I can't install these two packages to my project folder, receiving the error hints of `npm WARN my-project-name@1.1.1 No repository field.` `npm WARN my-project-name@1.1.1 No license field.` `npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Comment: The warnings are not so important, I guess they are missing fields in your package.json. However I have no idea about the `ERR`. Did you upgrade your nodejs to version 8? Or downgrade to version 6?

Comment: @yogurt After I upgraded my node.js from 7.6.0 to the latest 8.4.0, I tried running `npm install jshint --save-dev` and `npm install async --save-dev` in my project folder, and still got the same warning and error hints: `npm WARN my-project-name@1.1.1 No repository field.` `npm WARN my-project-name@1.1.1 No license field.` `npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined.` :-(